# Redirect to anchor

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect an url like this `domain.tld/instagram/anchor` to `domain.tld/instagram/#anchor`.

This should only happen on links with the instagram path and must be handled via .htaccess, I tried this and I'm now stuck because this does nothing:

```
RewriteRule ^/instagram/(\d[^/]+) /instagram/#$1/ [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^instagram/([^/]*)/?$ /instagram/#$1/ [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

***Important points:***

- Always use NE and NC flags to your rules to make sure conditions are well formed.
- You need not to use \d here in your regex since you are not having digits in your shown samples.
- You need to make sure to keep this Rules at top because of redirection it should come first, in case later we have other rules related to it.
- You need not to match `/` in starting here.

Comment: Worked well, had to chance the first `instagram` to `ig` to avoid constantly beeing redirected. I guess the server can't read anchors.

Comment: @Screenload, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.